# Issue while sourcing "setup" file

Tags: python, pip, alpine-linux

when i am running my source file for environment creation in python its showing following error:

```
Sending build context to Docker daemon  10.11MB
Step 1/19 : FROM python:3.6.8-alpine3.8 as base
---> b6bfe2b71f9d
Step 2/19 : FROM base as builder
---> b6bfe2b71f9d
Step 3/19 : RUN apk --no-cache --update-cache add gcc python python-dev py-pip build-base wget
---> Running in af525112b576
fetch http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.8/main/x86_64/APKINDEX.tar.gz
fetch http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.8/community/x86_64/APKINDEX.tar.gz
WARNING: Ignoring http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.8/main/x86_64/APKINDEX.tar.gz: temporary error (try again later)
WARNING: Ignoring http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.8/community/x86_64/APKINDEX.tar.gz: temporary error (try again later)
ERROR: unsatisfiable constraints:
 build-base (missing):
   required by: world[build-base]
 gcc (missing):
   required by: world[gcc]
 py-pip (missing):
   required by: world[py-pip]
 python (missing):
   required by: world[python]
 python-dev (missing):
   required by: world[python-dev]
 wget (missing):
   required by: world[wget]
The command '/bin/sh -c apk --no-cache --update-cache add gcc python python-dev py-pip build-base wget' returned a non-zero code: 6
alias: Unknown host
ifconfig: `--help' gives usage information.
bash: pipenv: command not found
```

any idea on this i have tried upgrading python pip but nothing helps

Comment: Looks like a network or server issue.

Comment: You need to get `apk update` to succeed. Once that's working - it says 'temporary error' here, but that's probably a network issue as Klaus says, since those URLs work for me - you can try this again. Try and work out why this server can't talk to dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org.

Comment: alright thank you so much i will check